# how to connect a website and desktop application with same database

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I have a ***desktop application*** and a ***website***. Desktop application in ***c#*** and website in ***ASP.Net***. I am using same database which is created in ***MySQL***. Now I have to upload my website. So now how can I have same database. What changes I need to connect them. I don't want synchronization.

Comment: Here is an example snippet:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-programming-connecting-open.html
What do you mean by synchronization ?

Comment: it means have 2 databases and after specific time data will be updated in both

Comment: in both application use same database connection string

Comment: my question is website will be uploaded as well as database but for desktop application It will not uploaded so how can I have same database

Comment: in desktop application use the connection of database that you will be uploading on server

Comment: you actually need to connect both application with same database; so use same connection string in both application for database connection

Comment: @EhsanSajjad ok. than may I need any reference to add in my project as I do when I add for MySQL?

Comment: are you already using mysql database with both application?

Comment: you just simply need to use one connection string in both applications that will be pointing to your mysql database, references are related to assemblies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to just make same database name, user_name, password and host name. For both. But one more this the flow of your desktop app and website code should be same.

Answer (score 0):

1 ) create account here -> https://www.freemysqlhosting.net/account/
2 ) Upload Your Database
3 ) User Same database credential

The limitation is of this solutions is, you required Internet in Desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

- Use same connection string for your deskstop application and asp.net application.

  connectionString="Server=100.20.58.6;Database=db_prime;Uid=admin;Pwd=pass22;Convert Zero Datetime=True" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"